# How do Time Machine's checksums work?

Tags: time-machine

The man page for `tmutil` mentions that Time Machine records checksums of files, and lists a `verifychecksums` command. The man page is sparse on details, and does not otherwise mention checksums. I was wondering whether Time Machine ever automatically verifies these checksums (or if these are only verified when you run `verifychecksums` manually)? The page also says checksums are not retroactively computed, so how can I list the files in my latest backup for which no checksum is available? Also, is it known what checksumming algorithm is used?

```
 verifychecksums path ...
         Compute a checksum of data contained within a backup and verify
         the result(s) against checksum information computed at the time
         of backup.

         No output is generated for matching checksums. Issues are
         reported using the following legend:

             !    The file's current checksum does not match the expected
                  recorded checksum.
             ?    The file's recorded checksum is invalid.

         Beginning in OS X 10.11, Time Machine records checksums of files
         copied into snapshots. Checksums are not retroactively computed
         for files that were copied by earlier releases of OS X.
```

The above is from the `tmutil` man page in OS X 10.11.6, maybe the one in macOS Sierra has more details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a partial answer to my own question: while I don’t know whether Time Machine ever automatically verifies the checksums, a [post on ycombinator.com](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=14129840) provided me with an answer to my other two questions. The checksumming algorithm is the same one as the default one used by the Terminal utility [`cksum`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/cksum). The checksum values are stored in the Time Machine backup as an extended attribute of each file (`com.apple.finder.copy.source.checksum#N`). So to list the files for which no checksum is available, you would search for all files in the latest backup without the attribute, using a Terminal command like this one:

```
find '/Volumes/Time Machine HD/Backups.backupdb/Mac/Latest' -type f -not -exec xattr -x -p 'com.apple.finder.copy.source.checksum#N' '{}' ';' -print 2>/dev/null | grep /
```

I’ll quote the [original post](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=14129840) for details on checking the stored checksum against the output of `cksum`:

> **RJIb8RBYxzAMX9u on Apr 18, 2017**
>   [...] In any case, the "hash" appears to be CRC32, stored in extended attributes:
>
> ```
> $ xattr .inputrc
> com.apple.finder.copy.source.checksum#N
> com.apple.metadata:_kTimeMachineNewestSnapshot
> com.apple.metadata:_kTimeMachineOldestSnapshot
> $ xattr -px 'com.apple.finder.copy.source.checksum#N' .inputrc
> 26 E5 4A AB
> $ cksum .inputrc
> 2873812262 65 .inputrc
> $ printf '%x\n' "$(cksum .inputrc | cut -d ' ' -f 1)"
> ab4ae526
> ```

Comment: That's very useful information, but I had to add `-print` before `2>/dev/null` to make your command work: `find '/Volumes/Time Machine HD/Backups.backupdb/Mac/Latest' -type f -not -exec xattr -x -p 'com.apple.finder.copy.source.checksum#N' '{}' ';' -print 2>/dev/null | grep /`

Comment: Thanks! The command was indeed missing `-print`, I fixed it.